# Help fixing odd AMOLED screen burn

Tags: samsung, screen

I just picked up a used Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge+ and when viewing light-colored screens, it's very clear that the keyboard is burnt into the panel with a pinkish hue.

What's the best (free/fastest) course of action to reverse this AMOLED screen's burn-in permanently, short of opening the phone and replacing the display assembly? Is there an app to try, or might inverting colors for a while help?

[image]

Comment: It would need replacement - apps in some cases can fix minor burn in but not of this nature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace the phone screen, Amoled is famous for not being able to fully recover, in most cases, from burning